# How to clear the cart using ajax in shopify?

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

I need to add link on home page or any other page with the help of that link I want to clear all my cart items.

can any one help me with this

Answer (score 0):

You can use Shopify's `clear.js` API. Follow these steps:

1. Add a link to clear cart:

```
<a href="/cart/clear" class="clear-cart">Clear Cart</a>
```

2. Add this script in your custom JS file:

```
$('.clear-cart').on('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/cart/clear.js',
    success: function(){
      alert('Cleared the cart!');
    },
    dataType: 'json'
  });
})
```